# AWS Free Tier Instances - Running two instances parallel from two Services

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can I run a EC2, t2.micro instance & a RDS db.t2.micro instance, parallel & continuously a whole month ? Or is it I can only run one of them ?

I know both of them have 750 hours of up time available in the free tier. But I'm bit confused whether it is (EC2 OR RDS) or (EC2 & RDS) in the free tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 750 hours per micro rds and 750 hours per micro EC2 instances.
https://aws.amazon.com/es/free/faqs/